# How do I limit access to wp-admin to an IP range?

Tags: login, htaccess, ip

I am trying to use the .htaccess file to restrict access to the wp-admin directory to an IP range as prescribed [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Limit_Access_to_wp-admin_by_IP)

```
# Block access to wp-admin.
order deny,allow
allow from x.x.x.* 
deny from all'
```

**It does precisely nothing:** I removed the allow line altogether and I am able to login just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have traced the problem to a set of directions in the .conf file:
the Virtual Host was missing this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Which made the server to ignore .htaccess files altogether.

The full answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from x.x.x
```

or

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from x.x.x.0/32
```

If on Apache 2.4 try this:

```
Require all denied
Require ip x.x.x
```

or

```
Require all denied
Require ip x.x.x.0/32
```

Comment: No. As I said, even the "deny from all" is not working, the syntax for IP range is a secondary matter.

Comment: Edited my answer since could be Apache version/syntax issue.  Or if you are running nginx then the answer is completely different.  if above is not working for you then best bet...head over to serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am running Apache 2.4. Ended up editing .conf file.

Comment: ok, the 2.4 answer above should have worked, as well.  All .conf is is a base set of rules - you sure you didn't just set the IP range for your entire site?

Comment: No, I used a directory tag. Trying your answer on another site.

Comment: "Require all denied" in the .htaccess file does nothing.

Comment: Something else going on then; that syntax is basic .htaccess; nothing esoteric or clever.  If you really want to get to the bottom of it either  post up your complete .htaccess file in your question or (even better) ask the question over on serverfault.